# DataPrep:How to reuse the recipe for multiple datasets

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

This is a DATAPREP Question:
I had to use google-cloud-datastore Tag as there is no Tag available for google-cloud-dataprep

Question:

I am using Dataprep to clean my data. I have multiple datasets(15) with the same structure/headers. I want to use the same recipe for all the datasets. Is there a way to import/reuse the previously created recipe for other datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not able to find [google-cloud-dataprep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataprep) tag because it is a StackOverflow tag (not ServerFault).

In the flow view page, you can "swap" the datasource for a recipe. If you want to use different follow-on steps for different data sources, you can "make a copy" of the recipe and then swap the data source of the copied recipe.

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934507/reuse-the-same-recipe-for-multiple-datasets) for the duplicate issue on StackOverflow.